# HASKELL --- Using "let" within a "do" syntax in GHCI

Tags: haskell, syntax, ghci, let

I know this works:

```
do name <- getLine; let nameTag = "Hello, my name is " ++ name in putStrLn nameTag
```

As well as this piece of code when loaded into GHCI:

```
hey = do 
    name <- getLine
    let nameTag = "Hello, my name is " ++ name
    putStrLn nameTag
```

But this does not work:

```
do name <- getLine; let nameTag = "Hello, my name is " ++ name; putStrLn nameTag
```

giving the following error message:

```
<interactive>:142:82:
  parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
```

Why doesn't it work? Can I make it work? If yes, then how?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The problem is that the parser thinks that the structure of your code is `let {nameTag = ... ; putStrLn nameTag}` where it expects an assignment instead of `putStrLn nameTag`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use braces around the let binding(s) to disambiguate the parsing:

```
do name <- getLine; let { nameTag = "Hello, my name is " ++ name }; putStrLn nameTag
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use parenthesis, but that didn't work out. What's the fundamental difference between curly brackets and parenthesis in Haskell?

Comment: @RafałPłaszczyk Brackets are for delimiting subexpressions. Curly brackets are for disambiguating language syntax. (Oh, and record syntax...)

Comment: @RafałPłaszczyk You probably noticed that Haskell is indentation-sensitive. Basically, brackets allow one to write everything in one line, writing blocks (`do,let,where,case of`) at the same indentation level as `{entry1;entry2;...}`. Usually not needed, except in GHCi. In many cases, only `;` are enough, and brackets can be omitted.

Answer (score 5):

To complement the answer by McKenna, the error can be explained as follows: compare these two lines

```
do name <- getLine; let name1 = "One"; putStrLn name1
do name <- getLine; let name1 = "One"; name2 = "Two"; putStrLn name1
```

A human reader can see that they actually mean

```
do { name <- getLine; let { name1 = "One" } ; putStrLn name1 }
do { name <- getLine; let { name1 = "One"; name2 = "Two" }; putStrLn name1 }
```

but the parser is not that smart.
When the Haskell parser sees the common code portion

```
do name <- getLine; let name1 = "One";
                                  -- ^ --
```

it has to decide whether the last `;` belongs to the `do` level (as in the first case above), or to the `let` level (second case). It turns out that it chooses `let`, and fails later on.